# Extjs - Unable to reload store with updated DB data

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, extjs4.1

I have added my code as below,
There is a drop down i have added in this code,
Based on the value of the drop down option selected, the grid data should be  populated.

I have passed the drop down data to the php code and got response from DB,

The result from DB should be reloaded in the same grid,

I am new to ExtJS, Hence kindly help me out,

Below is how my grid looks like, The selected drop down is where i have problem.

[image]

```
Ext.onReady( function() {
        var required = '<span style="color:black;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>';
        var win;
        var dropdownboxdisplay = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
                                name : 'ichannel',
                                store: [['B', 'Brochure'],
                                        ['D', 'Direct Mail'],
                                        ['L', 'Direct Mail LVIS'],
                                        ['K', 'EEU'],
                                        ['E', 'Email'],
                                        ['O', 'LOB Transfers'],
                                        ['N', 'No IVR Treatment'],
                                        ['C', 'Outward Callbacks'],
                                        ['T', 'Text']],
                                listeners : {
                                        change: {
                                                fn: function () {
                                                        var rolename = this.value;
                                                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                                                            url: 'getStratToggles.php',
                                                            method: 'GET',
                                                            params: {
                                                                "rolename" : rolename
                                                            },
                                                            success: function (response) {
//                                                              this.grid.getView().refresh(true);
//                                                              var jsonResp = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
//                                                              Ext.Msg.alert("Info","UserName from Server : "+jsonResp.messages[1].strategy_label);

                                                                Ext.Msg.alert("im here");
                                                                var gData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                                                                var aArray = new Array();
//                                                              alert(gData.messages.length);
                                                                for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
//alert(gData.messages[i].strategy_label+','+gData.messages[i].delinq_code+','+gData.messages[i].account_status+','+gData.messages[i].reason_code+','+gData.messages[i].balance_low+','+gData.messages[i].balance_high+','+gData.messages[i].ventile_low+','+gData.messages[i].ventile_high+','+gData.messages[i].dlq_history+','+gData.messages[i].slot_number+','+gData.messages[i].transfer_key+','+gData.messages[i].default_transfer);
                                                                        aArray[i] = "NA8725,90,,,NA8725,,1,6,,90,CARD_CA_CIB_MID,8889989149";//gData.messages[i].strategy_label+','+gData.messages[i].delinq_code+','+gData.messages[i].account_status+','+gData.messages[i].reason_code+','+gData.messages[i].balance_low+','+gData.messages[i].balance_high+','+gData.messages[i].ventile_low+','+gData.messages[i].ventile_high+','+gData.messages[i].dlq_history+','+gData.messages[i].slot_number+','+gData.messages[i].transfer_key+','+gData.messages[i].default_transfer;
                                                                }

                                                                 //Ext.getCmp('toggle_grid').getStore().load(aArray);
var gRecords = gData.records;
      Ext.iterate(gRecords, function(item) {
          var rec = Store.findExact('strategy_label', "NA8725");
          if (rec > -1) {
             Store.getAt(rec).set('strategy_label', true);
          }
      });
//var store = this.grid.getStore();
//grid.getStore().load(aArray);
//grid.refresh();
//                                                              this.getInfoGrid().getStore().load(gData);
                                                            },
                                                            failure: function(){console.log('failure');}
                                                        });
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        });

              var win = new Ext.Window({
                id:'detaileduser-win',
                border: 5,
                layout:'fit',
                width:400,
                height:500,
                plain: true,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                resizable:false,
                labelWidth: 150, // label settings here cascade unless overridden
                frame:true,
                bodyPadding: '5 5 0',
                bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
                items: form,
                buttons: [
                {
                        text:'Save',

                        handler: function(){
                                var basicForm = form.getForm();
                                var valArr = basicForm.getValues(false);
                                var dda = valArr.dda_code;
                                var ls = valArr.last_slot;
                                var ventile = valArr.ventile;
                                var lac = valArr.last_code;
                                var del = valArr.delinq_code;
                                var low = valArr.current_balance_low;
                                var high = valArr.current_balance_high;

                                if ( dda == "" && ls == "" && ventile == "" && lac == "" && del == "" && low == "" && high == "" ) {
                                        alert ( "Must fill out at least one more from group (DDA Code, Last Slot, Ventile, Last Action Code, Delinquency Code, Low Balance or High Balance) to submit form" );
                                        return;
                                }

                                form.onSubmit();
                        }
                },{
                        text: 'Close',
                        handler: function(){
                                win.close();
                        }
                }]
        });
        return { 'winObj':win, 'formObj':form };
}
        store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: [
                        'strategy_label',
                        'default_transfer'
                ],
                proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: 'getStratToggles.php',
                        reader: {
                                root: 'messages',
                                totalProperty: 'messageCount'
                        }
                },
                        autoLoad: true
        })
        store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: [
                        'strategy_label',
                        'delinq_code',
                        'account_status',
                        'reason_code',
                        'balance_low',
                        'balance_high',
                        'ventile_low',
                        'ventile_high',
                        'dlq_history',
                        'slot_number',
                        'transfer_key',
                        'default_transfer'
                ],
                proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: 'getStratToggles.php',
                        reader: {
                                root: 'messages',
                                totalProperty: 'messageCount'
                        }
                },
                        autoLoad: true
        })

        searchText.storeRef = store

        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                columns: [
                        {hideable:false,header: "Strategy Label", width: 80, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'strategy_label', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Stage of Delinquency", width: 110, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'delinq_code', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Account Status", width: 110, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'account_status', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Reason Code", width: 80, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'reason_code', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Balance Low", width: 70, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'balance_low', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Balance High", width: 70, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'balance_high', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Ventile Low", width: 70, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'ventile_low', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Ventile High", width: 70, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'ventile_high', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "DLQ History", width: 80, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'dlq_history', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Slot Number", width: 80, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'slot_number', align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Transfer Key", width: 150, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'transfer_key' ,sortable: false, align: 'center'},
                        {header: "Default Transfer", width: 90, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'default_transfer',align: 'center'}
                ],
        store: store,
        id: 'toggle_grid',
        multiSelect: true,
        autoRender: true,
        title: 'Strategy Admin',
        width:1070,
        tbar: [
                        {
                                text: 'Add',
                                iconCls:'add',
                                tooltip:'Create a new strategy',
                                disabled: hidden,
                                handler : function() { addGroupHandler(); }
                        },
                        '-',
                        {
                                text: ' Edit',
                                iconCls:'option',
                                tooltip:'Change the highlighted strategy settings',
                                disabled: hidden,
                                handler : function() { editGroupHandler(); }
                        },
                        '-',
                        {
                                text: ' Delete',
                                iconCls:'remove',
                                tooltip:'Delete the highlighted strategy',
                                disabled: hidden,
                                handler : function() {
                                        var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()
                                        if (record != "") {
                                                Ext.Msg.show({
                                                        title:'Delete Group?',
                                                        msg: 'Are you sure you wish to permanently delete the selected stragegy?',
                                                        buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
                                                        fn: function(btn) {
                                                                if (btn == 'yes') {
                                                                        var strat_lables = "";
                                                                        var newChannel = "";
                                                                        var tempChannel = "";
                                                                        for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {
                                                                                var Selected = record[i]
                                                                                var rec = Selected.data.strategy_label
                                                                                var newChannel = rec[0];
                                                                                if (( i == 0) || (newChannel == tempChannel )) {
                                                                                        strat_lables = strat_lables.concat( rec + ",");
                                                                                } else {
                                                                                        alert ( "Cannot delete from multiple channels!");
                                                                                        return;
                                                                                }
                                                                                tempChannel = rec[0];
                                                                        }
                                                                                DoStrategyDelete(strat_lables);
                                                                }
                                                        },
                                                       icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING
                                               });
                                        } else {
                                                Ext.MessageBox.alert( 'Error', 'Please select a row first.' );
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        '-',
                        {
                                text: ' Rollback',
                                iconCls:'option',
                                tooltip:'Rollback the highlighted strategy settings',
                                disabled: hidden,
                                handler : function() { RollbackGroupHandler(); }
                        },
                        '-',
                        searchText,
                        '-',
                        dropdownboxdisplay
                ],

                viewConfig: {
                        plugins: {
                                ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                                dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize',
                                enableDrag: !viewOnly,
                                enableDrop: !viewOnly
                        },
                        listeners: {
                                beforedrop: function(node, data,overModel, dropPosition, dropFunction) {
                                        var groupPattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+/
                                        var indexPattern = /[0-9]+$/
                                        var currRecord = data.records[0].data
                                        var currRecord_start_label = currRecord.strategy_label
                                        localStorage.currRecord_start_label=currRecord_start_label;
                                        var currStratGroup = groupPattern.exec(currRecord.strategy_label)
                                        var currStratIndex = indexPattern.exec(currRecord.strategy_label)
                                        var overRecord = overModel.data
                                        var overStratGroup = groupPattern.exec(overRecord.strategy_label)
                                        var overStratIndex = indexPattern.exec(overRecord.strategy_label)
                                        var updatedStratLabel = ""
                                        if (overStratGroup[0] != currStratGroup[0]) {
                                                alert('Cannot move strategies between different channels')
                                                return false;
                                        }
                                },
                                drop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition) {
                                        var start = localStorage.currRecord_start_label
                                        var groupPattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+/
                                        var indexPattern = /[0-9]+$/
                                        var currRecord = data.records[0].data
                                        var currStratGroup = groupPattern.exec(currRecord.strategy_label)
                                        var currStratIndex = indexPattern.exec(currRecord.strategy_label)
                                        var overRecord = overModel.data
                                        var overStratGroup = groupPattern.exec(overRecord.strategy_label)
                                        var overStratIndex = indexPattern.exec(overRecord.strategy_label)
                                        /* Complicated Logic
                                                *
                                                * If groups are the same:
                                                * If the record was dropped after (below a record)
                                                * then we need to add 1 to the index. If it is less
                                                * than 10 we prepend the 0.
                                                *
                                                * If the record was dropped before (above a record)
                                                * then it will take on that label
                                                */
                                                var updatedStratLabel = ""
                                                if (overStratGroup[0] != currStratGroup[0]) {
                                                        //this should be caught in the before drop listener
                                                } else {
                                                        if (dropPosition == 'after') {
                                                                if (overStratIndex[0].substring(0,0) == 0) {
                                                                        overStratIndex = parseInt(overStratIndex[0])
                                                                } else {
                                                                        overStratIndex = parseInt(overStratIndex)
                                                                }
                                                                updatedStratLabel = currStratGroup + overStratIndex
                                                        } else if (dropPosition == 'before') {
                                                                updatedStratLabel = currStratGroup + overStratIndex
                                                        }
                                                }
                                                sortGroupHandler( start, updatedStratLabel );
                                                //console.log( start + "-->" + updatedStratLabel );
                                        }
                                }
                        },
                        //height: 500,
                        renderTo: 'tableHolder'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to do AJAX call in your `dropdownboxdisplay`'s `change` event listener. Instead, you simply apply the selected `rolename` parameter to the `store`'s proxy and reload the store:

```
store.getProxy().setExtraParam('rolename', rolename);
store.load();
```